# Write.csv writes unix executable file mac

Tags: r, macos, csv, unix

I am working in an online server (running in windows) using a VPN.

I have a mac computer and recently upgraded R and installed R-3.6.3.nn.pkg (regular) version.

I am working with data frames (.csv) that I merge into a compiled dataframe

I want to create a .csv from this compiled dataframe

Problem: write.csv seems to work BUT the file produced is a unix executable file!

I have never had this problem before until now

The files are saved in csv - utf-8 and were converted from an excel file

any idea about how can i fix this problem?

I just want to be able to write .csv as normal .csv

Thank you

This is my code:

```
setwd("/Volumes/eds/data/XXX/YYYYY/Pigments")

Month <- read.csv("Pigments ma.csv")
Month <- cbind(Month, Month = c("March"))
mar <- Month

Month <- read.csv("Pigments ap.csv")
Month <- cbind(Month, Month = c("April"))
apr <- Month

Pigments <- rbind(ma, apr)

write.csv(Pigments, "Pigments Year.csv ")
```

Comment: You can change the permission of the file using `chmod` else check default setting for new file creation in your `.profile`

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice the space after .csv in the file name you write to, but before you close the quote marks? Remove that space and you should be sweet.